# Can I load and use a model in MY_Controller using CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 3 and I need some data available to all methods. I will query the data from the database and then I need to display it on every page.

I have created a MY_Controller extending CI_Controller and saved it in /application/core/

But I am getting this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Area_model::get_user_locations()`

MY_Controller:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $location_data;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('area_model');
        $org_id = $this->session->userdata('org_id');
        $this->location_data = $this->area_model->get_user_locations($org_id);
    }

}
```

Can i access models and the database from within MY_controller?

Area_model.php

```
// get all areas for an organisation
public function get_user_locations($org_id) {
    $areas = $this->db->get_where('areas', array('org_id' => $org_id));
    $area_array = $areas->result_array();
    return $area_array;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Can you post the Area_model code?

Comment: Added area_model above

Comment: Is that all that is in the Area_model.php? If so then you need to put that function in a class: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Comment: Yes the area model is named Area_model.php and declared class Area_model extends CI_Model {

Comment: Are you calling `__construct()` in `Area_model()`? If not, make sure you are and make sure to call the parent constructor (see the basic prototype on the CI model documentation page).

Comment: Also try calling `$this->Area_model->get_user_locations($org_id)` (capitalize the 'Area_model')

Comment: Can you please show us your complete `Area_model.php` code

Answer (score 0):

MY_Controller

not used to direct any function to __construct()
__construct to only load to any model
write other function to MY_Controller look like this

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $location_data;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('area_model');
        $org_id = $this->session->userdata('org_id');
    }
}

function functionname()
{
        $this->location_data = $this->area_model->get_user_locations($org_id);
}
```

Area_model.php

```
public function get_user_locations($org_id)
{
    $areas = $this->db->get_where('areas', array('org_id' => $org_id));
    $area_array = $areas->result_array();
    return $area_array;
}
```